# $\int \sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}dx $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}dx $$

My attempt requires two substitutions, I was wondering if there's any other way of solving this, including hopefully an elegant trig sub

let $x=u^4$
so we now have

$$\int 4u^3 \sqrt[3]{1+u } du $$

now , again let $1+u= z^3$

so we have $$12\int  z^2(z)(z^3-1)^3dz$$

Which is

$12(\frac{z^{13}}{13} - \frac{3z^{10}}{10}+\frac{3z^7}{7} -\frac{z^4}{4} +1)$

which is an elementary , albeit lengthy integral , however, as mentioned earlier, I was wondering if there's any other way of solving this

Source :- A problem book in mathematical analysis

Comment: After putting,$1+u=z^3$,in next line,in place of $u^3$,it would be $(z^3-1)^3$. Isn't it? Also in the place of 12,the coefficient would be only 4,that is you have written total coefficient,12*3=36,but I think it would be 4*3=12.Check it once again!

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad, will correct it in a few minutes

Comment: Why don't you simply substitute the entire "rooted" thing: $u=\sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}$? :-)

Comment: @Dominique, I didn't because then $g(x)dx=du$ (where g(x) is the derivative of what you said is $u$ would be  really ugly and I'm not sure how to deal with that many  $x$s when we need the function in terms of u

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let,
$$ \sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}=u $$
and then
$$ x=(u^3-1)^4.$$
So,
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int \sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}dx=\int u\cdot4(u^3-1)^3\cdot3u^2du\\
&=&12\int u^3(u^3-1)^3du=\int(u^{12}-3u^9+3u^6-u^3)du\\
&=&\frac{12}{13}u^{13}-\frac{18}{5}u^{10}+\frac{36}7u^7-3u^4+C\\
&=&\frac{12}{13}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}\right)^{13}-\frac{18}{5}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}\right)^{10}+\frac{36}7\left(\sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}\right)^7-3\left(\sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}\right)^4+C.
\end{eqnarray}$$

Comment: In the expansion of cube,you have written wrong sign.Also,in the last 2 lines,all terms should be multiplied by 12. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just forgot the coefficient. Thanks.

Comment: Also check the sign of expansion.

Comment: Does the last term miss a negative sign?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int \sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}dx $$

let $x=u^4$
So we now have

$$\int 4u^3 \sqrt[3]{1+u } du $$

now , again let $1+u= z^3$

so we have $$4\int (z^3-1)^3 (z) 3z^2dz$$

$$=12\int z^3(z^3-1)^3  dz$$
$$=12\int z^3(z^9-3z^6+3z^3-1)  dz$$
$$=12\int (z^{12}-3z^9+3z^6-z^3) dz$$
$$=\frac{12z^{13}}{13}-\frac{36z^{10}}{10}+\frac{36z^{7}}{7}-\frac{12z^{4}}{4}+c$$
$$=\frac{12z^{13}}{13}-\frac{18z^{10}}{5}+\frac{36z^{7}}{7}-3z^{4}+c$$

$$=\frac{12}{13}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}\right)^{13}-\frac{18}{5}\left(\sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}\right)^{10}+\frac{36}7\left(\sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}\right)^7-3\left(\sqrt[3]{1+ \sqrt[4]x}\right)^4+c$$

where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

I think it is correct form of your method.It is not another method.

Comment: Thanks! Upvoted, but I'll wait for a few days in hopes of getting another method,  before accepting .hope you understand )

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever yes,I also think about it!